# Array of objects with unique properties

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Is there a way to declare an interface that one of the properties is an array of objects and inside those objects we have a property that acts similarly to a "primary key" in a database structure? To not allow repetition.

```html
interface a {
  myList: {
    uniqueName: string;
  }[]
 }
 
 
 const myAObject: a = {
   myList: [
    {
      uniqueName: "bla-1"
    },
    {
      uniqueName: "bla-2"
    },
    {
      uniqueName: "bla-1" //shouldnt allow that
    }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a Record<> to achieve something similar:

```html
interface myThings = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

type item<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  name: string;
  value: T[K];
}

type items<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: Record<K, item<T, K>> }[keyof T];

const myItems:items<myThings> = {
  a: { //this uniqueness is enforced with Record<>
    name: "some name"
  },
  b: {
    name: "some name"
  },
  c: {
    name: "some name"
  } 
}
```